# Webpage not running on normal chrome tab

Tags: web-development-server

I am unable to load my website on a normal chrome tab hosted at Digital Ocean. Although it is working fine in the incognito tab. I tried it on my friend's laptop but it worked on a normal tab also on that laptop. I am unable to get the error. My domain name is "crunchstocks.com" and the IP address is 104.248.3.239.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you double checked the DNS records are all 100% correct? Also, did you get D.O. to generate an SSL certificate? Finally, if you are running Wordpress, it could be an auto block script to stop would be hackers trying to guess the password when you log in.

Another thing you could try is to use your phone as a wifi hotspot and then try again, as the server will see you as a different user (your IP address will be different). Hope that gives you some ideas to try.

Comment: I have not generated an SSL certificate till now. I am using NodeJs at the backend. I am using my mobile's hotspot but it is still not working. Although when I am using the IP address of droplet it is working fine.